# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning in iOS7 - viewWillAppear not called

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to get the hang of the new viewController animations in ios7 but I am encountering a road bump when trying to use core animation.

Im finding that after the transition has completed, the controller of the 'to view' does not seem to be receiving the typical view lifecycle methods, i.e. `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`. I'm calling completeTransition: but that doest seem to be enough -- is this typical behavior? Or am I doing something wrong? here is my code:

```
-(void)executeDismissalAnimation:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
UIView *inView = [transitionContext containerView];

UIViewController *toViewController      = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *fromViewController    = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

toViewController.view.hidden = NO;

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    [fromViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}];

CGFloat duration = 0.4f;
CAKeyframeAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
scaleAnimation.values = [self floatValuesFromValue:1.f toValue:1.5f withEasingFunction:ExponentialEaseInOut];
scaleAnimation.duration = duration;
scaleAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
scaleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
[fromViewController.view.layer addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:nil];

CAKeyframeAnimation *alphaAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
alphaAnimation.values = [self floatValuesFromValue:1.f toValue:0.f withEasingFunction:LinearInterpolation];
alphaAnimation.duration = duration*2;
alphaAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
alphaAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
[fromViewController.view.layer addAnimation:alphaAnimation forKey:nil];

CAKeyframeAnimation *scaleAnimationB = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
scaleAnimationB.values = [self floatValuesFromValue:0.6f toValue:1.0f withEasingFunction:ExponentialEaseInOut];
scaleAnimationB.duration = duration;
scaleAnimationB.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()+0.3;
scaleAnimationB.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
scaleAnimationB.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[toViewController.view.layer addAnimation:scaleAnimationB forKey:nil];

CAKeyframeAnimation *alphaAnimationB = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
alphaAnimationB.values = [self floatValuesFromValue:0.5f toValue:1.f withEasingFunction:LinearInterpolation];
alphaAnimationB.duration = duration;
alphaAnimationB.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()+0.3;
alphaAnimationB.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
alphaAnimationB.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[toViewController.view.layer addAnimation:alphaAnimationB forKey:nil];

[CATransaction commit];

}
```

Comment: You should expect to see `viewWillAppear:` called before the transition begins, and `viewDidAppear:` called after it completes. Not sure what was going on in this case.

Comment: You need to explicitly call these functions.